# How to use mean-admin module in MEANJS

Tags: mongodb, express, meanjs

Hi am new to meanjs i would like to know about how to use mean-admin module in my existing project while am executing  this command 
mean user admin@admin.com -a admin
 this error is comming 
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/lib/cli.js:1088
      if (err) throw new Error(err);
                     ^
Error: Error: Cannot find module '/Users/JineshJohn/Desktop/SOA/server/config/env/development.js'
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/lib/cli.js:1088:22
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/lib/cli.js:111:21
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/lib/utils.js:49:14
    at fs.js:272:14
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)

Answer (score 1):

MeanIO has modules that are not compatible with MeanJS. There is an open ticket regarding your inquiry [here](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/issues/41). I think I remember seeing the MeanJS team talk about releasing an administration module in an update, but I have yet to see it.

Comment: there actually is a [mean-admin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mean-admin) package, it's just not officially released yet.